# how to get camera matrix(flir c3)&while i using flir c3, is there any way to output the temparature?

Tags: python

## I'm using C3 to do fever detection and grabbing frame of eyes&mouth using dlib and opencv

i don't find any information about how to get camera matrix from FLIR official website or any lib to calculate it
while i using C3 to get the value of the temperature, i want to compute on python is there any way to output it?
i try to use Spinview but it didn't support C3

```
` if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    video_stream = FileVideoStream(sys.argv[1]).start()
    file_stream = True
    liveness_detection(video_stream, file_stream) 
  else:
    video_stream = VideoStream(src=0).start()
    file_stream = False
    liveness_detection(video_stream, file_stream) `
```

Comment: Do you mean the camera distortion matrix? You can determine it empirically using [opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html). The process is not specific to your model of camera. Manufacturers don't provide this information because it differs per-camera due to mechanical inconsistencies.

Comment: Ask about getting the temperature in a separate post.